# Botão é disparado mesmo desabilitado, o que fazer?

Tags: c#, webforms

Tenho um linkButton que é desabilitado via servidor, assim:

```
lkExcluir.Enabled = false;
```

Código:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lkExcluir" runat="server" Text="[Excluir]" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="lkExcluir_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir');"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Se eu clico no botão desatibado, é exibido a mensagem **Tem certeza que deseja excluir** caso **ok** é dispoarado o evento `lkExcluir_Click`, o que devo fazer para não exibir a mensagem e consequentemente não dispara o evento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa desabilitar o OnClientClick também no mesmo lugar onde coloca o Enabled = false.

```
if (lkExcluir.OnClientClick != null)
{
    lkExcluir.OnClientClick = null;
}
```