# Como executar uma função do JS antes da chamada método do CodeBehind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eventos, eventos-do-mouse

Tenho um button asp

```
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancarEndereco" runat="server" 
   cssclass="btn btn-success btn-lg"   text="Avançar >">
</asp:button>
```

que tem um evento do `VB` atrelado no `click`

```
Private Sub cmdAvancarEndereco_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
                                      Handles cmdAvancarEndereco.Click

'evento

End Sub
```

porem no clique deste bottao, eu preciso executar antes do evento `cmdAvancarEndereco_Click` um evento do javascript:

```
var getCardToken = function () {
// evento
}
```

tentei colocar isso sem sucesso ele vai direto pro server:

```
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdAvancarEndereco")
        .addEventListener("click", getCardToken);`
```

Alguma solução?

Comment: coloca Onclientclick no button e chama a função! Aqui nessa minha [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41743/bot%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-disparado-mesmo-desabilitado-o-que-fazer) dá  pra saber como que fica o button!

Comment: Tenta isso pra ver se resolve.. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/181725/64073

Comment: Cara infelizmente nao vejo como duplicata, pois a pergunta la nao tem a ver com como executar primeiro e sim qual executar primeiro e nenhuma solução foi dada igual aqui, os questionamentos são diferentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o atributo **OnClientClick** com o retorno da sua função (tem que retornar true ou false), se retornar true ele chama o o evento no CodeBehind.

```
<asp:button ID="cmdAvancarEndereco" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-success btn-lg" text="Avançar >" OnClientClick="return getCardToken()"></asp:button>
```

Comment: é possivel fazer mais que uma chamada de função ? 
exemplo :

`<asp:button ID="cmdAvancarEndereco" runat="server" cssclass="btn btn-success btn-lg" text="Avançar >" OnClientClick="return getCardToken(); teste();"></asp:button>`

Comment: Sim, é possível, você poderia fazer: `if(primeiraFuncao) { return segundaFuncao(); }`

Comment: Ótimo muito obrigado !